# grapqhql does not return null on null object

Tags: express, graphql

In the API I am developing this graphql query

```
query { user(id: "nonexistentID") { name email } }
```

returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "name": null,
      "email": null
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd like it to return null on the user like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

so the API-user knows that there's no such user. Is this intended behaviour or am I missing something?

The schema definition in graphql-js(express) looks like this:

```
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Query',
        fields: {
            user: {
                type: userType,
                args: {
                    id: { type: GraphQLString}
                },
                resolve: function resolve(root, args, info) {
                    return adapters.users.byId(args.id);
                }
            }
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: What is return value of `adapters.users.byId(args.id);`? Can you put a debug statement in the resolve function?

Comment: ^ agreed. It looks like `adapters.users.byId(args.id);` is returning an empty object which causes any of its child resolvers i.e. `name` and `email` to return null. If you want the user to be null make sure `adapters.users.byId(args.id);` is returning null.

Comment: Thank you both. By checking again, I found that the adapters.user.byId wasn't returning null but instead a promise. I should have immediately noticed the mistake. Thanks again for making me _think_.